# NDSolve swapping between solution branches to stay positive

Tags: differential-equations

I have a differential equation that I wish to solve, with the requirement that my independent variable must stay positive, but do not require it to remain differentiable. My equation comes from minimising a (constrained) variational principle using calculus of variations.

An example equation is:

```
DSolve[{z[s] (s - z[s] z''[s] - z'[s]^2) == 0, z, s]
```

which has three solutions:

$$z = 0, \pm \frac{\sqrt{s^3 + 6 C_1 + 3 s C_2}}{\sqrt{3}}$$

For some values of the boundary conditions, one of the non-zero roots will provide a solution which becomes imaginary at an interior point. At this point, I need the $z=0$ solution to be chosen, then swap back to the solution which satisfies the boundary conditions once it is real again. For instance, $z(0)=1,z(3)=2$ shows this behaviour.

How do I automate this?  Note that I can't use NDSolve on the equation above, as it gets upset due to the presence of the `z[s]` term, and also that this degenerate condition may not be just $z=0$ in my actual example, it can be any non-differential equation involving $s$ and $z$. So this fails:

```
NDSolve[{z[s] (s - z[s] z''[s] - z'[s]^2) == 0, z[0] == 1,   z[3] == 2}, z, s]
```

Solutions using only DSolve are not going to work for more complicated equations (like my real ones).

Comment: So, you can't use `NDSolve` *and* you can't use `DSolve`? That's a problem. I think without further context, this is hard to answer. For instance, what are you *doing* with these solutions? You said you are varying boundary conditions, but in what context? Do you just need it to spit back a solution, either 0 or one of the others, based on the choice of BC? Or are you constructing a function of the BC, etc. More info please!

Comment: How about you remove the offending `z[s]`, use `NDSolve`, get a solution, return the solution if it's real and 0 if it's complex?

Answer (score 1):

For the example problem, you can get a result that may be what you are seeking by a change of variable.

```
y[s] == z[s]^2
Table[D[%, {s, n}], {n, 0, 2}]
Append[%, z[s] (s - z[s] z''[s] - z'[s]^2) == 0]
Eliminate[%, Table[D[z[s], {s, n}], {n, 0, 2}]]
Assuming[y[s] != 0 && y'[s] != 0, FullSimplify[%]]
DSolve[{%, y[0] == 1, y[3] == 4}, y, s]
Plot[Sqrt[y[s]] /. %, {s, 0, 3}]
```

### [image: solution]

Comment: I have actually used y=z^2 to get to this point, my initial variational principle is in terms of y, but I want to restrict y to be positive.